# Python percentage function not working as intended

Tags: python, list

For a college project I need to output of the number of votes + the percentage of votes out of the total votes for each team that (input)(there are six in total).

I made the program using lists, and got to the part where i made a list with 7 elements: the total number of votes the program registered + the votes consecutively each team got.

I then use this list to run a function that changes the values of the indexes of the list to their percentage, with another function working as a percentage calculator. (Called 'porcentagem' that I tested out and works as intended.)

```
def porcentagem(p, w):
  pc = 100 * float(p)/float(w)
  return str(pc) + "%"
```

---

```
def per(list):
    listF = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for x in list[1:7]:
        if x != 0:
            listF[x] = porcentagem(x, list[0])
        else:
            listF[x] = 0 
    return listF
```

For some reason when I input the votes, the results come all out of order. For example:
The list input is `List = [6, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,]` but the output is `[0, '16.666666666666668%', '33.333333333333336%', '50.0%', 0, 0, 0]` (Index 0 is the total if it wasn't clear, and

I have no idea what could be causing this, its changing the orders of the elements apparently (its supposed to come out as 50%, then 33,3...% etc..)

I'm 'new' at programming + spent two months not coding anything + english is not my first language and I'm learning python in portuguese, sorry if it looks obvious lol

Comment: You probably don't want `listF[x]`, you want to use something else as an index.

Comment: `listF` is being assigned based on the *value* of `list`. You probably want it to be the index of the value instead.

Comment: What do you want your output to be, given your input?

Answer (score 1):

The `x` in `for x in list[1:7]:` returns the actual value, not the index. So `x` will be: 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0. That means the first `listF[x]` is `listF[3]` which is assigning to the 4th element.

A word of caution: `list` is a constructor for a built-in function, so if you use `list` as a variable, it might have unintended consequences. Change it to something like `percentage_list`.

Do something like the following:

```
def per(per_list):
    listF = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(1, len(per_list)):
        x = per_list[i]
        if x != 0:
            listF[i] = porcentagem(x, per_list[0])
        else:
            listF[i] = 0 
    return listF
```

Output: `[0, '50.0%', '33.333333333333336%', '16.666666666666668%', 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Alternatively you can use `for i,x in enumerate(per_list):`

Comment: Oh that's right, thanks a bunch man.

Comment: @MarkRansom Indeed, that was my first thought as well, but that might have raised more questions ;)